# How use universal struct

Tags: go

I have struct for order list. I want order `map` and find it way. But i don't want create this for all types, that i have. Maybe I need another code? Or how I can rewrite it for universal, that I can use it with all types, that have `Prev` and `Next`.

```
type Post struct { //for example
    P string
    O int
    Prev, Next *Post
}
type Act struct {
    I int
    Prev, Next *Act
}    

type Map struct {
    Act         map[int]*Act
    First, Last *Act
}

func (m *Map) New(a *Act) int {
    Ida++
    f := Ida
    a.Id = Ida
    m.Act[Ida] = a
    if m.First == nil {
        m.First = a
    } else {
        m.Last.Next = a
        a.Prev = m.Last
    }
    m.Last = a
    return f
}

func (m *Map) Del(s int) {
    if _, ok := m.Act[s]; ok {
        if m.Last == m.First {
            m.Last = nil
            m.First = nil
            delete(m.Act, s)
            return
        }
        if m.Last == m.Act[s] {
            m.Last = m.Act[s].Prev
            m.Act[s].Prev.Next = nil
            delete(m.Act, s)
            return
        }
        if m.First == m.Act[s] {
            m.First = m.Act[s].Next
            m.Act[s].Next.Prev = nil
            delete(m.Act, s)
            return
        }
        m.Act[s].Prev.Next = m.Act[s].Next
        m.Act[s].Next.Prev = m.Act[s].Prev
        delete(m.Act, s)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. Go does not have generics :)

Comment: @Nadh I must rewrite it? can you answer another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887596/golang-map-sort)? I don't use array for order, because element, that before need element, can be delete earlie. And i worry, that it delete another element

Answer (score 2):

You can define function which would work with all types that implements `Prev()` and `Next()` methods. For example something like this

```
type List interface{
    Next() List
    Prev() List
    First() List
    Last() List
    Value() interface{}
    SetNext(List)
    SetPrev(List)
}
func Del(l List, elem_to_delete interface{}){
    for e:=l.First(); e != l.Last(); e = l.Next()
        if l.Value() == elem_to_delete{
            l.Prev().SetNext(l.Next())
            l.Next().SetPrev(l.Prev())
            break
        }
    }
}
//and implement those methods for your types
type Post struct { //for example
    P string
    O int
    Prev, Next *Post
}
func (p Post) Next() List{
    return p.Next
}
...
//and then you can call Del() with any of this types
Del(post, 5)
```

Also Go have list data structure defined in [stdlib](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/container/list/) which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

If to define `Next` and `Prev` operations as methods:

```
type Act struct {
    I int
    Prev, Next *Act
}

func (a *Act) GetNext(){
    return a.Next
}
```

you could have an interface:

```
type PrevNext interface {
    GetNext() *Act
    GetPrev() *Act
    // ... and all other required actions
}
```

So you could define `Del()` not as method but as generic function which expects object of `PrevNext` type with all required operations defined as methods.

```
func Del(m *PrevNext, s int) {
    if _, ok := m.Act[s]; ok {
        if m.GetLast() == m.GetFirst() {
            m.SetLast(nil)
            m.SetFirst(nil)
            delete(m.Act, s)
            return
        } 
    // ....
    }
}
```